# Does vertical-align:center-right; works?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a image vertical aligned in the right.

```
.header {   
    background-color:white;
    width:auto;
    height:120px;
}

.title {
    vertical-align:center-right;    
}

<div class="header">
          <div class="title">

                    <a href="home.html"><img src="logo.png"/></a>

          </div><!--TITEL DIV-->
     </div><!--HEADER DIV-->
```

But the content in the 'title' div won't vertical align in the right center.

Comment: text-align is not vertical align... its for text aligning horizontally and can only have one of the 3 values: left, right and center.

Comment: Plz share your HTML and CSS code and be specific what you want to achieve??

Comment: `Text-align` is only horizontal. You need to use `vertical-align`.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen not working

Comment: @Bayern What is not working? If you want to use vertical-align you need to make sure that the div is the full height.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen the image just stays at top

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen edited

Comment: What is the size of the image?

Comment: @Bayern, to see how to vertically align, see duplicate and then just add text-align right to the result

Comment: @Pete not working, tried that before i posted this question...

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen 250x76

Comment: Did you have a look at all the answers - the first one is a bit outdated - take a look at the flexbox approach

Comment: @Pete whatever I try it stays at top.......

Comment: You are not trying very hard then as there are detailed instructions in those answers with very good examples

Answer (score 0):

```
.title{
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Right works, but stays at top

Comment: use `line-height` i think it work

Comment: Still on top :D